# Can't get category of post with an ACF built module - Timber/Twig/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm having trouble using the traditional methods of getting a associated category/categories with a post. I have built a relational module in ACF Builder that is related to all posts, and they show up with a twig dump command, but all attempts at getting the associated categories return nothing.

The php markup associated with the modules is:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new Timber\Post();

$context['categories'] = $post->terms( array(
    'query' => [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
    ],
) );

Timber::render( array( 'templates/landing-page.twig', 'page.twig' ), $context );
```

This returns an empty string. post.categories returns nothing, and even wordpress functions aren't returning anything. I'm essentially trying to just get the post name, image, and the associated category name.

Comment: Here's my best guess at what you're asking: you want to use an ACF field to add categories to your posts, but when you do, those categories are not seen by timber, or by any other WP functions? Mainly, I'm unsure of what you mean by "I have built a relational module in ACF Builder that is related to all posts"

Comment: Hey Jesse, I was able to get all of the associated categories by turning the posts that were returned into Timber posts. This was done in the .twig file inside the Loop. ```{% for article in Post(module.article) %}``` this changes a WP_Post into a Timber_Post, which allows us to use Timber functions, such as .terms(). 

```<p class="sl_article__category">Posted in: {{ article.terms('category')|first }}</p>```

returned the desired result.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but I'm still missing a bit of context. The code you show in your question is for a single post template. I would only expect `context['categories']` to return the categories of the current post, not of any posts selected in an ACF relationship field. Also, what is `module`, which you use in your follow-up comment? Is that the field name of your relationship field?